# Java Plugins with depedencies

Tags: java, plugins, reflection

I am working on a project that needs a plugin system.

So far I have created my own class loader and am able to dynamically load external jars, that I have created.(they all implement the same interface.

Now, those plugins require external libraries themselves. Unfortunatelly this only seems to work, when I include the required libraries when building the main application. Then my plugins also work. Otherwise, when not adding the libs to the main programm I get classNotFoundExceptions when ever I try to instanciate a plugin.

What I want to do, is include the required libraries in the plugin jars, as I ship them.

So I have 2 questions:

```
 - is it even possible to access those libs referenced by the plugins when they are   included there or do I have to manually load them too
 - if it is possible to include them, how do I extract them into the plugin jar? (just like when building a runnable jar)
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Is there any reason why you're not just using an established framework like OSGi for this? Either Eclipse/Equinox, or Apache Felix?

Comment: Well thanks. I will have a look at either, when I find time. Though I think it really helps to understand the internal workings a little better. So getting my approach to work (if at all possible) might be a good training, if not fit for shipment.